# iso file size for 13.04 is larger than cd's available space

Tags: 13.04

The iso file for ubuntu 13.04 is larger than most of the cd's where we burn the file. What do we have to do about this situation?

Answer (score 4):

The ISO is intended for DVDs and USB sticks. If you don't have a DVD or USB stick consider using the mini.iso:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry my friend, the ubuntu team [can't fit the image to a cd anymore](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/its-official-the-ubuntu-livecd-is-dead), you can however use a dvd, or other installation methods, see this articles : [Ubuntu installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)  ;  [5 alternative ways to install ubuntu](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-alternativ-ways-install-ubuntu-linux/)